# Are there any patterns to observe in choosing the correct negative prefix to use?

Tags: adjectives, prefixes, negative-prefixes

Are there any patterns to observe in choosing the correct negative prefix to use, as in ***un**believable*, ***dis**proportionate*, ***a**symmetric*, and ***in**tolerable*? (There are other negative prefixes as well, but these are the ones I usually mix up.)

*Un-* and *in-* are probably the ones I most frequently mix up, as in **untolerable/intolerable*, **unedible/inedible*, **unexact/inexact*, **unappropriate/inappropriate*, ...
I realize these are all *in-*, but why? Is there anything to look for there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agreeing with the answer Shinto Sherlock gave from Fowler, [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm) says,

> In general, words take *un-* when they
>   are of English (Germanic) origin and
>   *in-* if they come from Latin. (The
>   forms *im-, il-,* and *ir-* are variations
>   on *in-*.) Apart from that, there’s
>   really no good guide to which one you
>   should choose.

Following the link will give you an expanded discussion of this topic.

Comment: wasn't a- also for Latin / French derived words?

Comment: Hi Daniel, u mentioned about a link in your last statement. Where is the link?

Comment: @PartTimer the link is above the quote or here is the url: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm.

Answer (score 7):

**a-** and **an-** are used in words with Greek origin, (meaning *no*, *absence of*, *without*, *lack of*, *not* in said language). Other Greek prefixes are **ana-**, (meaning *again*, *up*, *on*, *above*, c.f. *anabaptist* literally meaning "re-baptist") and **anti-** (meaning *against*, c.f. *antidemocrat*).

Anyway, the thing is that as language is a living thing with lots and lots of users (especially in the case of English, where there also are a lot of different cultures, further contributing to the confusion), and therefore, rules like this tend to be mixed up (especially when creating new words or combining already existing ones). The rule of thumb is that, as previously stated:

- **un-** is used in words of Germanic origin,
- **in-** in words of Latin origin (and generally in words from other Latin-derived languages, like Spanish or French),
- **a-** and **an-** is used in words of Greek origin.

Prefixes like **de-**, **dis-** and **dys-** come from Latin or Greek and have a slightly different meaning.

Note that **un-**, **in-** and **a-**/**an-** have the same origin, but they have taken very different ways into our language of today.

Comment: *-dys* is obviously not from Latin. Here's a hint: the Latin name for Y is *I Graeca* - the *Greek I*.

Comment: There are exceptions, especially in more recent words: *amoral* (Greek *a* + Latin) was coined to be distinct from *immoral*. Similarly, *asexual*.

Comment: There are exceptions, especially in more recent words: *amoral* (Greek *a* + Latin) was coined to be distinct from *immoral*. Similarly, *asexual*. Also *unattractive* and *undaunting* are non-Germanic.

Answer (score 2):

Fowler says:

> The general principle that *un-* is English and belongs to English words, and *in-* is Latin and belongs to Latin words, does not take us far.

There is a lot more which [you can read in Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vr7muDFR6j4C&lpg=PA262&dq=fowler%20modern%20english%20usage%20uncertainty&hl=en&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q=fowler%20modern%20english%20usage%20uncertainty&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is to choose the prefix according to the etymology of the word:

- Germanic or neologisms: *un-*
- Latin or French: *in-*, *im-*, *ir-* [depending on the subsequent letter](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/673/87231)
- Greek: *a-*, *an-*

However, the *un-* prefix is usually used for Latin derivatives that end in suffixes such as *-ed* and *-able* , resulting in adjectives such as *unfounded*, *unassailable*, and *unbelievable*. This to prevent confusion with another Latin prefix with identical appearance but a different meaning of "to cause to", which appears in words like *illuminate*, *irradiate*, or *inflame*.

Latin-derived words with *un-*:

- unattractive
- unconscious
- undaunting
- unfortunate
- unimportant
- unpleasant
- unpopular
- unprepared
- unproductive

Roots with different prefixes for adjective and noun forms:

- *unstable* and *instability*
- *uncivil* and *incivility*
- *unable* and *inability*

Roots with both *un-* and *in-* variants with distinct connotations:

- *inhuman* and *unhuman*
- *indigestible* and *undigestible*
- *inconsolable* and *unconsolable*
- *inartistic* and *unartistic*

### Sources

- Domínguez, Inma. (25 March 2011). [Negative prefixes before adjectives](http://inmadom-myenglishclass.blogspot.com/2011/03/negative-prefixes-before-adjectives.html). *My English class*.
- Herrmann, Nicola (7 February 2018 [2014]). [In- vs. Un- Which Prefix should I use?](https://blog.online-spellcheck.com/english/vs-un-prefix-use/) *Online Spellcheck Blog*. Radolfzell, Germany: QaamGo Web GmbH.
- Okrent, Arika. (18 July 2014). [What's the Difference Between In- and Un-?](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57840/whats-difference-between-and-un) *Mental Floss*.
- user-27118. (22 July 2019 [2010]). [Negative prefixes](https://grammarist.com/usage/negative-prefixes/). *Grammarist*.
- Quinion, Michael. (13 May 2000). [Un- versus In-](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm). *World Wide Words*.