# Prefixes for the opposite of "perishable": unperishable, non-perishable, imperishable

Tags: meaning, antonyms, prefixes, negative-prefixes

*Unperishable*, *non-perishable* or *imperishable*? I'm quite confused about which prefix is used for the opposite of *perishable.* If more than one is used, what are the differences between them? Searching online did not really give me any answers. I hope someone here can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any patterns to observe in choosing the correct negation prefix to use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/are-there-any-patterns-to-observe-in-choosing-the-correct-negation-prefix-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the common ones first, *nonperishable* and *imperishable*:

> **nonperishable**: not subject to rapid deterioration or decay. [source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonperishable)
>
> *A supply of nonperishable food was kept for emergencies.*

*Nonperishable* and its typically plural noun form, *nonperishables*, are used for concrete objects, like food, supplies, and medications, that are intended to last a long time.

> **imperishable**: not subject to decay; indestructible; enduring. [source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/imperishable?s=t)
>
> *Though Thelonius Monk died decades ago, his imperishable legacy arouses our senses still today.*

I mostly see *imperishable* used in a literary or abstract context. It can also be used for items, but this usage is less common.

*Unperishable* means the same as *nonperishable*, but is the least common of all ([source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=non%20-%20perishable%2Cunperishable%2Cnonperishable&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnon%20--%20perishable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnon%20--%20perishable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNon%20--%20perishable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunperishable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cnonperishable%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnonperishable%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNonperishable%3B%2Cc0)). I've never seen it used.

[image]

Comment: Wow!  I now know which one to use for what I'm writing. I think its safe to say I won't be using unperishable anymore. Thanks Ash.

Comment: But this is readily available to OP; I'm not saying that this isn't more than could be expected from a new visitor, but I am saying that a question with no signs of reasonable research should be close-voted instead of answered.

Answer (score 1):

To add onto the excellent answer above, I got curious about the use of "un" with "perishable", and guessed I would find mostly stylized choices...I did find a few artistic uses.

However, here's what I found out about "un" unto itself (very cool):

This is from:  **The Un-Believable Un-Verb**
September 21, 2009
By Ben Zimmer

Check out the whole article at:  https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/the-un-believable-un-verb/

> > Ever since Old English, the un- prefix has come in two basic flavors.
> >     It can be used like the word "not" to negate adjectives (unkind,
> >     uncertain, unfair) and the occasional noun (unreason, unrest,
> >     unemployment). Or it can attach to a verb to indicate the reversal of
> >     an action (unbend, unfasten, unmask).
>
> Actually, that's a bit of an oversimplification. Yale linguist
>   Laurence Horn, my trusty guide through the thickets of un-, points out
>   that in Old English the two flavors corresponded to two distinct
>   prefixes. On the one hand there was the negative prefix un-
>   (etymologically related to German un-, Latin in-, and Greek a[n]-),
>   and on the other hand there was the reversative prefix on(d)- (related
>   to German ent- and Greek anti-). **These two prefixes merged into one
>   form, un-, and they've been semantically intertwined ever since.**
>
> So the new un-verbs that I discuss as typifying "The Age of Undoing"
>   owe their legacy to the old reversative prefix on(d)-. But the other
>   prefix in Old English, negative un-, could negate not just adjectives
>   and nouns but some verbs too: unbe, unbecome, and unhappen are all
>   attested in Old English with simple negative meanings ('not be,' 'not
>   become,' 'not happen'). By the Middle English era of Chaucer, these
>   negative verbs had faded away, so unlove (used by Chaucer in his poem
>   Troilus and Criseyde) didn't have the meaning 'not to love' (negative)
>   but rather 'come to no longer love' (reversative). And this is the
>   type of unloving that has been handed down to modern-day country
>   singers like Lynn Anderson ("How Can I Unlove You?").

Comment: That's really interesting...i love how modern English has roots in Old English or even most other languages for that matter. This just makes me look at prefixes in a whole different light. Now it makes me curious about the origin of the other prefixes in the English language.