# How did English get related words from the same Latin root but different negative prefixes?

Tags: etymology, negative-prefixes

I see that there is [no consistent rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2532) in English for which words use which negative prefix, but *in‐* is generally for Latin roots and *un‐* is generally for Germanic roots. However, I find it especially surprising that some related English words derived from the same Latin roots use both, eg:

- *unmoved* and *immovable*
- *unstable* and *instability*
- *undetermined* and *indeterminate*
- *unvaried* and *invariant*

How did this happen historically? Were words with one prefix introduced to English in a different era than words with the other prefix?

Comment: @Knotell Your interest in the post is welcome. You may not have known, though, that the comment thread is reserved for friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid
discussion or debate in comments.
A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The pattern seems to be based on word endings, not just on word roots

I think that the examples that you mention actually can be explained synchronically for the most part, if we look at the  morphological structure of the words. So even though you asked about history, I will take a bit of a detour in the first part of this answer to talk about the behavior and distribution of the negative prefix *in-* in present-day English.

Whether the root of the word is from Latin or from English (Germanic) doesn't actually seem to be as relevant as whether the *ending* of the adjective is from Latin or from English.

The negative prefix *in-* is not very productive in English<sup>1</sup>: that is, it's rare for a speaker to take an English adjective and attach *in-* to it to create a *new* negative adjective. Rather, *in-* (or *im-, ir-,* or *il-*) mainly shows up on words that already existed with this prefix in Latin or French before they were adapted for use in English. For example, before the word *instability* was used in English, *instabilité* was used in French.

The adjectives *moved, determined* and *varied* were derived in English by the addition of the native English suffix *-(e)d* to the English verbs *move, determine* and *vary.* The suffix *-(e)d* is a sign that these words were not taken directly from Latin adjectives.

In contrast, adjectives ending in “-ble”, “-ate” and “-ant” often do come from Latin adjectives (the corresponding Latin endings in the nominative masculine singular are *-bilis, atus* and *-ans*), and consequently, many adjectives with these endings have corresponding negative adjectives starting with *in-/im-/ir-/il-.*

The reality is a bit more complicated than my description in the preceding paragraphs—see my answer to the older question "[Why do we say INcomplete but UNcompleted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212119)" for some more details and citations. But it seems to be fairly clear that if you look at a negative adjective ending in the suffix *-ed*, it is much more likely to be prefixed with *un-* than with *in-*, regardless of whether the adjective is built on a Germanic or Latin root.

### Historically, *un-* is the older suffix

Of course, English is a Germanic language, and so the Germanic prefix *un-* has a longer history of use in English than the prefix *in-,* which is from Latin and French.

I don't know yet how the negation of adjectives with Latin or French roots has evolved over time.

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) entry for *unstable* has a citation dated a1340 and one that is more tentatively dated to "?c1225". The earliest OED citation for *innocent,* with the Latin/French negative prefix, is from "a1340". So it seems safe to say that during the Middle English time period, words starting with negative *in-* entered the language, but the native English prefix *un-* was already being used on some words of Latin or French origin.

The OED entry for the negative prefix *in-* suggests that its usage has changed some over the centuries, and mentions the substantial overlap with the usage of *un-* which has resulted in some amount of variation for a number of words:

> In English *in-* (*il-, im-, ir-*) is a living negative suffix for words of Latin or Romanic origin, freely used, even when no corresponding formation appears in Latin; in this use it interchanges to some extent with the Old English negative *un-,* which is used in native or thoroughly naturalized words, e.g. *incautious, uncautious, in-, un-ceremonious, in-, un-certain, in-, un-communicative, in-, un-devout, in-, un-distinguishable.* In such cases the practice in the 16th and 17th c. was to prefer the form with in-, e.g. *inaidable, inarguable, inavailable,* but the modern tendency is to restrict *in-* to words obviously answering to Latin types, and to prefer un- in other cases, as in *unavailing, uncertain, undevout.*

Keep in mind that this entry "has not yet been fully updated (first published 1899)" and it may have some inaccuracies. I think the author may have been overstating things a bit with the wording "**freely** used": Dixon, who I cited above and link to below, says *in-* is "seldom used to derive new [words]" (p.73) and categorizes it as "scarcely productive" (p. 73-74).

I will try to find a more modern academic source to cite about the history of the prefix *in-* in English.

#### Citation footnotes & links

1. *[Making New Words: Morphological Derivation in English](https://books.google.com/books?id=MmTRCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73),*
   by R. M. W Dixon (2014), p. 73-74.

Answer (score 1):

Up until about 1000 years ago, English was a pretty standard Germanic language in the Indo-European family. This means it had a fairly consistent grammar/syntax and a predictable morphology.

Then in 1066, French-speaking Normans invaded and conquered England. The end result was that the nobility spoke French (romance) and the mass populace spoke English (germanic). After a couple hundred years of mixing, the end result is modern English. A very irregular, inconsistent language.

edit: Just to be clear, 'in' comes from French, 'un' is Germanic. They are both used because of the history of English.

Comment: This answers why English in general is inconsistent but it doesn't mention anything specifically about "un" vs. "in", which is what the question is specifically asking about.

Comment: I have noticed, for what it is worth, from working in international companies, that the language group who seem to have the greatest difficulty with selecting "un..." or "in..." are Germans. One colleague could never get away from things like "unpossible" and "inofficial". Having said that the US Declaration of Independence, composed by Thomas Jefferson, I recall referred to "unalienable". It used to be a source of amusement to that same German colleague, that in the USA's first document, the "un" and the "in" got confused.

Comment: This leads to the further question of why there are variant forms for what one might assume was all the same thing in the first place. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/n%CC%A5- gives  *n̥-* as a variant of   *ne*, that is, a voiceless *n*. Whilst you can use this by itself as a syllable, many languages prefer to add a vowel and this reference shows that virtually any vowel can be added, either before or after the *n* across the range of languages.

Comment: To show the range available just in Britain I looked up the Welsh word *ANeglur*  in  http://www.geiriadur.net/index.php?page=ateb&term=aneglur&direction=we&type=all&whichpart=exact  and I found amongst other meanings,  *UNclear* adj. *INdistinct* adj.  *ILlegible* 
 (from *INlegible*). Can anyone find any other vowels in the same element in English (or any other language with origins in Britain!)?